# Translation of the Russian term "распорядок дня"

Tags: nouns, translation, russian

Russian has the term "Распорядок дня." It means a to-do list of things that you do every day or your "order of life" (routine). For example:

> Get up at 7:00
>   Work from 9:00 to 15:00
>   Go to sleep at 22:00

A similar term is "schedule," but a schedule may be different every day. "Распорядок дня" is always alone.
Is there such a term in English?

Comment: Please use [a bilingual dictionary](http://www.lingvo-online.ru/ru/Translate/ru-en/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F), or take such questions to our chat. The main site is not a free translation service. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your “[routine](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/routine?s=t)”. The things you do day in, day out, usually at the same times. If you use “routine” like this it will be understood in British English; if you want to be more specific use “daily routine”.

> **noun**
>
> 1. a customary or regular course of procedure
> 2. commonplace tasks, chores, or duties as must be done regularly or at specified intervals; typical or everyday activity: 
>      the routine of an office
> 3. regular, unvarying, habitual, unimaginative, or rote procedure.
>
> Source: *Dictionary.com Unabridged*. Based on the Random House Dictionary, © Random House, Inc. 2015.